# PHP - Split binary number string into smaller chunks

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a large binary number stored as a string in a variable. Something like this :

```
10111100100001010101010101010100000111111111001010101...
```

I want to split it in chunks of 8, so I use this : `chunk_split($text, 8);` but chunk_split() returns a string.

**How do I store all the chunks in an array ?**

Comment: Please use the search function before asking. thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If you want the 8 bits stored as a string within the array use:

```
str_split($text, 8);
```

Or, the bits themselves can be chunked as a set of arrays:

```
array_chunk(str_split($str), 8);
```

Comment: Got it. It's done like this : `str_split($text, 8);`